# Using AudioRecord's data outside Android

Tags: android, audio, stack-overflow, audiorecord

I'm trying to stream the audio data recorded on android to a micro-controller for playback. the audio is recorded using the AudioRecord class and is then sent over UDP. on the receiving side, the micro-controller receives the data and plays it using PWM. there are a couple of problems though :

- I don't exactly know what format the AudioRecord class uses. i'm using ENCODING_PCM_16BIT but don't even know if its bipolar or not and how to convert it to unipolar if it is.
- Due to limited bandwidth, i can't send more than 8 bits per sample. since 8 bit PCM isn't supported on my phone, i've used the 16 bit version but for conversion, i've just used the upper 8 bits. i'm not sure if that's right.
- Since i've used a weird Crystal Oscillator for my circuit, the audio has to be sampled at 7.2kHz. my phone supports 8kHz sampling so i just use that and send %90 of the recorded data (using a for loop with a float as variable).
- I've hooked up a 2W speaker to the OC2 pin on my ATmega32 using a 220 Ohm resistor and a 100nF capacitor to act as a filter. ([Schematic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sTtMz.png)) but again i'm not sure if its the correct way to do it.

So all of this put together produces nothing but noise as output. the only thing that changes when i "make some noise" near the MIC is the volume and the pattern of the output noise. the pattern doesn't make any sense though and is the same for human voice or music.

This is the piece of code i wrote to convert the data before sending it over UDP :

```
float divider = 8/7.2f;
int index=0;
recorder.read(record_buffer,0,buffer_size);
for(float i=0;i<buffer_size;i+=divider)
{
    send_buffer[index++]= (byte) (record_buffer[(int)i] >> 8);
}
```

I don't know where to go from here. any suggestion is appreciated.

Update:
I took RussSchultz's advice and sent a sine wave over UDP and hooked up the output to my cheap O-Scope. this is what i get:

```
No Data : https://i.stack.imgur.com/1XYE6.png
No Data Close-up: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ip0ip.png
Sine : https://i.stack.imgur.com/rhtn0.png
Sine Close-up: https://i.stack.imgur.com/12JxZ.png
```

There are gaps when i start sending the sine wave which could be the result of buffer overflow on the hardware. since the gaps follow a pattern, it can't be UDP data loss.

Comment: first off, break the problem apart.    Make sure you can UDP a known signal over to your device.  A square wave with 2 samples high, two samples low, repeat *ad nauseum* should be good enough to prove that that aspect is working right.   You can also capture your UDP data on a PC on the network and write the data out and graph it in excel (or whatever graphing tool you have).

Comment: your 16->8 bit solution should be fine

Comment: As part of breaking the problem apart, verify your "DAC" is working with a sine wave.  Compile in a 256 sample sine wave and output it.  Make sure it sounds right (and looks right on the O-Scope).

Comment: @RussSchultz i have a (crappy but good enough) O-Scope so will try that. thank you. will try to send [this](http://extremeelectronics.co.in/avr-tutorials/sound-generation-by-avr-micro-tutorial-i/).

Comment: @RussSchultz got some explanation for the noise. gonna set a flag for buffer overflow and report back

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so after working on this for a month i got it to work.

- I don't exactly know what format the AudioRecord class uses. i'm using ENCODING_PCM_16BIT but don't even know if its bipolar or not and how to convert it to unipolar if it is.
- Due to limited bandwidth, i can't send more than 8 bits per sample. since 8 bit PCM isn't supported on my phone, i've used the 16 bit version but for conversion, i've just used the upper 8 bits. i'm not sure if that's right.

its was bipolar. i had to convert it to 8 bit by adding half the dynamic range to each sample and taking the upper 8 bits.

- Since i've used a weird Crystal Oscillator for my circuit, the audio has to be sampled at 7.2kHz. my phone supports 8kHz sampling so i just use that and send %90 of the recorded data (using a for loop with a float as variable).

even though i have a slight frequency shift, its still acceptable.

- I've hooked up a 2W speaker to the OC2 pin on my ATmega32 using a 220 Ohm resistor and a 100nF capacitor to act as a filter. (Schematic) but again i'm not sure if its the correct way to do it.

i changed the filter to an exact 3.6KHz low pass RC one (using one of the many online calculators). the speaker should not be connected directly because it requires a current uC can't provide. you will still get an output but the quality is not good at all. what you should do is drive the speaker using a darlington pair or (as i have) use a simple op-amp circuit.